# How to change the Kinect point cloud resolution

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, resolution, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to change the Kinect point cloud resolution, via openni_camera or openni_node, such that fewer points are returned ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9318/how-to-change-the-kinect-point-cloud-resolution/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the **Changing driver settings** section of the [openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) wiki. The parameter you'd want to tweak is **depth_mode**. The Kinect openni_node driver supports VGA(640x480), QVGA(320x240), and QQVGA(160x120) resolutions of the point cloud, all at 30Hz.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-03-10**:
Please mark the question as answered.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-07**:
Ok, using a value of 8 for both depth and image I can get the QQVGA resolution.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-03-07**:
Are you sure? I think I used the 160x120 before. Make sure you select the 30Hz though, otherwise it won't work

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-07**:
It looks as if the QQVGA resolutions aren't available, but QVGA does work and gives a much better update rate.